# Booting into single user mode by default

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, single-user

I want to force myself to use the command line interface of OS X. How can I make my Macbook Air boot into single user mode **by default**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Terminal.app and enter:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-s"
```

In the future your Mac will always boot to single user mode until you remove (`sudo nvram -d boot-args` or `sudo nvram boot-args=""`) or replace the boot-args.

Other boot-args directly modifying the boot mode:

`sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`: verbose
`sudo nvram boot-args="-x"`: safe mode

Comment: Whoa. You can even do this?

Comment: Does the SIP actually have to be deactivated for this?